# creating multiplication table using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create multiplication table using php as follows:

```
<?php

$cols = 10;
$rows = 10;
?>
```

... lot of html code ...

```
<?php

echo "<table border=\"1\">";

        for ($r =0; $r < $rows; $r++){

            echo('<tr>');

            for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++)
                echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td></tr>');

        }

        echo("</table>");

?>
```

I probably miss something but can't figure out what is it.

Any advices would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `</tr>` part should be echoed only once per row.

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: What u mean? I should edit post somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

you are closing tr tag for each column. 
you need to close tr tag after cloumn for loop.

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";

        for ($r =0; $r < $rows; $r++){

            echo'<tr>';

            for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++)
                echo '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>';
           echo '</tr>'; // close tr tag here

        }

  echo"</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you Awlad that is all i need! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `</tr>` tag to outside the inner `for` loop:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";

for ($r =0; $r < $rows; $r++){

    echo('<tr>');

    for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++)
        echo( '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>');

    echo('</tr>');

}

echo("</table>");
```

Comment: Thank you FreshPrinceOfSO! :)