# PHP script that creates the following table (use for loops)

Tags: php, logic

In one of my project I want to have pattern of certain number as depicted in image but its little chnaged, Any help will be appreciated

```
<?php  
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) {   
        echo "<tr> \n";  
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) {   
            $p = $col+1 * $row+1;  
            echo "<td>$p</td> \n";  
        }  
        echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    echo "</table>";  
?>
```

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating multiplication table using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968849/creating-multiplication-table-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
remove increment in your $col and $row

```
echo "<table border ='1' style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) {   
    echo "<tr> \n";  
    for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) {   
        $p = $col * $row;  
        echo "<td>$p</td> \n";  
    }  
    echo "</tr>";  
}  
echo "</table>";
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php  
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) {   
        echo "<tr> \n";  
        for ($col = 1; $col <= 10; $col++) {  
            echo "<td>" . $col * $row . "</td> \n";  
        }  
        echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    $temp = $i;
    for ($m = 1; $m <= 10; $m++) {
        echo "<td>" . $temp . "</td>";
        $temp += $i;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<?php  
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++)
    {
        echo "<tr> \n";  
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++)
        {
           $p = $col * $row;
           echo "<td>$p</td> \n";  
        }  
        echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    echo "</table>";  
    ?>
```

Comment: can you explain why $row*1?

Comment: I think no need to do that. we should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo"Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834";
echo"<br />";
echo "-------The table of 5-------";
echo"<br/>";
$s=5;
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
$t = $i*$s;
echo $s."*".$i."=".$t."<br/>";
}
?>
------------Output Section-------
Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834
-------The table of 5-------
5*1=5
5*2=10
5*3=15
5*4=20
5*5=25
5*6=30
5*7=35
5*8=40
5*9=45
5*10=50
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain at least a bit *how* your code works, and not just post plain code.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here<?php  
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) {   
    echo "<tr> \n";  
    for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) {   
        $p = $col+1 * $row+1;  
        echo "<td>$p</td> \n";  
    }  
    echo "</tr>";  
}  
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: use script for moor and moor updates in your web pages

Answer (score 0):

The Same code you use but you seen who you putted ($p = $col+1 * $row+1), u just gotta take the "+1" out in both, take care :)

```
<?php  
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";  
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) {   
        echo "<tr> \n";  
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) {   
            $p = $col * $row;  
            echo "<td>$p</td> \n";  
        }  
        echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    echo "</table>";  
?>
```

Comment: Escape character `=\"1\"` for what?

Comment: when you take =\"1\" the output will not start with 3, it will start with 1, and the this : ($p = $col * $row;) will work, making it look like the "Expected Output" that he asked for.